# cordova-plugin-calendar : Not working in Ionic App

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to implement calendar event in my ionic app using the below plugin.

```
cordova-plugin-calendar
```

I am following the below documentation:

```
https://github.com/didinj/ionic3-angular5-calendar-ui-event
https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0bb8f780aca75eadc12d6b/build-ionic-3-angular-5-calendar-ui-with-event-integration
```

My config.xml file has below entry

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-calendar" spec="5.1.5" />
```

In my plugins folder also this plugin is available.

But when i click on "Save", i am receiving the below error.

```
Failed! plugin_not_installed
```

Please suggest where i am doing the mistake. [Please see the app image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt6w0.png)

My ionic version details are as below:
Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
```

I am using the below commands to install the calendar plugin:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/calendar
```

Comment: try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-calendar

Comment: I will have to completely redesign. I want to use the ionic [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/calendar)

Comment: can you please explain your USE CASE?

Comment: 2 Use cases: 1. User can add/edit/delete a calender event directly from the app. That event will be saved the device calender.

Comment: 2. The app will display all listed events in the app also which are saved through the app. User will click on each day and see the event he has saved on each day by clicking on the date from the calender.

Comment: Are you Debugging it on real device or in Browser?

Comment: I have debugged in browser. In browser error is Cordova not found. This is fine I guess, as Cordova will not be device. Then I checked in emulator as well as in real device. Error is plugin not installed. The error is coming when I am trying to access device calender via the plugin. Somehow the app is not able to detect the plugin. I not able to find th exact reason.

Comment: What command are you using to install it? Also tell me your Ionic and Cordova versions

Comment: I have edited the original query and provided the details.

Comment: Update your ionic CLI and try again.

Comment: Tried but same error.